# Is there a limit as to how many apple TVs i can connect to 1 iTunes account?

Tags: itunes, appletv, accounts

Im speccing a house that has 8 individual TVs. The plan is to have an apple TV local to each TV. Will i have an issue with limits as to how many apple TVs i can connect to 1 iTunes account ?

Im based in the UK, not sure if that makes a difference in relation to the terms & conditions that govern this.

Comment: [This](https://support.apple.com/HT204074) implies that the limit is 10 devices, but doesn't explicitly mention Apple TVs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Home Sharing in iTunes, and sign into each ATV's "iTunes and App Store" account setting with the same account, and you'll be all set.  You can also set the ATV's to require the acct password to purchase content (or even to download free content), so you don't have to worry about guests/kids/etc purchasing content.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly in violation of the iTunes license in the us if you exceed 10 iTunes account authorizations total, 5 of which can be a computer. See under the redownload section

> Associated Devices Rules: You can have 10 devices (but only a maximum of 5 computers) signed in with your Apple ID at one time.

Apple Music also has a 10 device limit. Lastly, the terms are for personal, non-commercial use. I doubt Apple would go after some using 20 tv personally, but you never know if your account looks like it's being used not for personal, non-commercial use.

- http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/

I would set up family sharing and run one account on the 8 tv and keep your master account on your computers and devices.

You could also explore MDM like [jamfnow](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/) or Apple Configurator if you want to automate updates and setup for more than a handful of devices.

Oddly, apple exempts iOS devices but not tvOS devices from this authorization / sign in language. ( See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201251 )

As long as you don't need redownloads, don't need simultaneous use of tv-like/Netflix streaming or Apple Music on any/all devices or have any Macs under the same Apple ID, you should be fine with dozens of Apple TV under one AppleID/iTunes account per the license in the U.S. or U.K.

Comment: There is nothing in the (US) Apple Media Services Terms and Conditions that mentions Apple TV's.  Although ATV's require you to sign into your iTunes acct, they don't appear to count as "devices", only computers and iOS devices count toward the limit.

Comment: @jimtut the restriction is Associating your Apple ID and not about Apple TV explicitly. App licenses, paid programming, Apple Music, many features are labeled for personal, non commercial use. iOS is explicitly exempted - my suspicion is Apple agreements with cable providers won't allow Apple TV to be relaxed for some months or years, but that Apple doesn't go out of their way to disable someone just because of excess TV sign in.